# $( "#target" ).submit(); not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

For some reason I don't get why my form is not submitting using [$( "#target" ).submit();](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js'></script>    
<script>
function saveItem()
{
    console.log($("#frm"));
    $("#frm").submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frm" action="form.php" method="post">
    <a href="javascript:;" title="Save" onclick="saveItem()">save</a>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Save</button>        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does href expression <a href="javascript:;"></a> do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755088/what-does-href-expression-a-href-javascript-a-do)

Comment: @Mahi Why is this a possible duplicate?

Comment: @Archer in one of answer it is written that  link itself not to do anything,

Comment: `javascript:;` is same as `javascript:func();` with no function called

Comment: @Mahi But there's an inline event handler, so that simply makes the link do nothing and **then** the inline handler should be executed.

Comment: If I have console.log($("#frm")); in saveItem() function, it shows in Console. No error @NewToJS.

Comment: Do you have any other fields in Form? Just a guess, but maybe it does not send as there isn't anything to send?

Comment: Or maybe it does send but there's nothing to see.  Is this page form.php?

Comment: `id="submit"` overrides `submit()` DOM method of `form`. Use different id

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff - this is the issue. I changed the id and it now works.

Comment: @Archer sorry you were correct

Comment: Btw you've wired up the click handler to the link but not the button

Comment: @Brian this is expected result obviously

Comment: It looks suspiciously like a mistake - 2 elements next to each other with the same text - I would have expected that either both trigger the same handler or that the anchor is supposed to wrap the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id  attribute cannot be `submit` in the form element try another name .

[why we shouldn't set id as submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) ?

because If a form control (such as a submit button) has a name or id of submit it will mask the form's submit method.

Comment: It can but it shouldn't for any element nested inside a `form`. BTW, it is the same for `name` attribute. EDIT: i didn't downvoted it...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id="frm" action="form.php" method="post">
    <a href="#" title="Save" onclick="saveItem()">save</a>
</form>
```

Delete submit button if you want submit form by JS. And change element type,

```html
<span>
```

for example.