# Selenium: Getting ultimate href/link without clicking on it when it's a javascript call

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am webscraping a long table of html links (allowed under ToS).  However, all the links are javascript calls (href="javascript:;") so using get_attribute() to get the link will not work.  I don't want to actually click on all the links since it will download a large pdf file for each one

Is it possible to get the ultimate href/link that is called, without actually clicking the link and downloading the file?

Thank you!

Comment: You’ll need to be much more specific. There are many ways that a site could ultimately trigger a navigation, meaning there’s no generic way of capturing it. You’ll need to provide a specific example.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not easy - you need to take a look at javascript beyond those links, probably the links are generated dynamically.

The idea of doing this `<a href="javascript:;"></a>` is described here
[What does href expression <a href="javascript:;"></a> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755088/what-does-href-expression-a-href-javascript-a-do)

In short: in HTML for `<a>` to render correctly you need to set `href`, but sometimes there is no direct link or it's calculated somehow - so you need to look at javascript code which performs **handling** of those links - probably it's some `click` event listener you need to find