# What does href=javascript:{} do?

Tags: javascript, html, href

What is the reason for using `javascript:{}` in the code below. Is it similar to `href="javascript:"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"`?

```
<a href="javascript:{}">This is an example</a>
```

Comment: Sort of - yes, it's the same as those. It disables the link.

Comment: My friend your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7755207/10325004

Answer (score 5):

Let hyperlink look like a link but didn't link anything.

```html
<a href="javascript:{}">This is an example</a>
```

if you remove `href` attribute, that `a` tag will be normal text.

Answer (score 5):

It makes a button act like a link, but lets you execute custom JS code instead of linking to a webpage.

For example:

```html
<a href="javascript:{ document.write('hi u just pressed me');}"> Press me pls </a>
```

acts like

```html
<div onclick="doOnClick()"> Press me pls </a>
<script>
    function doOnClick(){ document.write('hi u just pressed me'); }
</script>
```

but the browser treats the former like a link.

Comment: Excellent example, I wasn't thinking about it being inline JS. So, in my example, this "{}" is really a NOP.  Any distinction between this example and removing the empty braces?

Comment: Very late response, but yes, the "{}" is a NOP. Curly braces can act like code blocks. So in the case of my example, it would have been interpreted as a code block. But I believe that the empty curly braces would be interpreted as the declaration of an empty object.