# Warning: A future version of React will block javascript

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I cloned repo from gitlab and installed the dependencies then When I type `yarn next dev` from command line I get

```
index.js:1 Warning: A future version of React will block javascript: URLs as a security precaution. Use event handlers instead if you can. If you need to generate unsafe HTML try using dangerouslySetInnerHTML instead. React was passed "javascript:;"
```

error. And in the browser I get err `code 404` on landing page. What is wrong I could not manage to get over.

Comment: what repo you cloned because there is an error in the code!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that somewhere in this code you have an element with an explicit javascript code somewhere in it's attributes. Something along the lines of

```html
<a href="javascript:;" ...>...</a>
```

as the warning mentions: `React was passed "javascript:;"`. This is probably some old repo, that was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755088/what-does-href-expression-a-href-javascript-a-do) to get away with `<a>` tags that do not lead anywhere. The more common solution to this is usig `href='#'`.

However, the 404 you are getting is probably signifying something more and the repo itself is probably broken.

Comment: but # appends in url which i don't want to.

Comment: you can style a button to look like an <a> tag.

Comment: `<a href={undefined} ... >` also works!

Comment: @Nawaz you just made me loosing 10 minutes. It does not work, it breaks the whole functionality of the <a> tag.

Comment: It seems different versions of ReactJs treat this differentky. There doesn't seem to be any good suggestion that works for all.

Answer (score -2):

You can define a component based on `a` element. The followings are a bunch of code snippets.

```js
import React, { FC, MouseEvent } from 'react'
import classnames from 'classnames'

import './navigator.scss'

export interface INavigatorProps {
  className?: string
  prefixCls?: string
  style?: React.CSSProperties

  url: string

  onClick?: (event: MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) => void
}

export const Navigator: FC<INavigatorProps> = ({
  style,
  children,
  url: oldUrl,
  className = '',
  onClick: oldOnClick,
  prefixCls = 'pa-navigator',
}) => {
  const classNameString = classnames(className, prefixCls)

  let [url = oldUrl, onClick = oldOnClick] = []
  if (/^javascript:/.test(url) || url === '#') {
    // @ts-ignore
    url = undefined

    onClick = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation()

      oldOnClick?.call(Object.create(null), event)
    }
  }

  return (
    <a
      href={url}
      style={style}
      className={classNameString}
      onClick={onClick}
      rel='noopener noreferrer'
    >
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}
```