href="javascript:;" from argon dashboard 2
I'm currently trying to implement Argon Dashboard 2 for a project using CodeIgniter 4. I have questions about several sections such as the navbar, dropdown, etc. there is the syntax href="javascript:;". Which file does the JavaScript function come from?
example :
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb bg-transparent mb-0 pb-0 pt-1 px-0 me-sm-6 me-5">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm">
      <a class="opacity-5 text-white" href="javascript:;">Pages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-white active" aria-current="page">
      Dashboard
    </li>
  </ol>
  <h6 class="font-weight-bolder text-white mb-0">Dashboard</h6>
</nav>

Sorry if the question I asked was not understandable
I have tried deleting this code in the footer to testing UI
<script src="../assets/js/argon-dashboard.min.js?v=2.0.4"></script>

but there is no change.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755088/what-does-href-expression-a-href-javascript-a-do

Use the Event Listeners sidebar in the Elements tab of DevTools to find out what's handling the click events on that element.
